# Draw augmented matrix in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I'm trying to create a very simple matrix in Tikz: can anybody help me with this?
The matrix should look like this:

[image]

Thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  In general you will get much more useful answers if you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: So do you want text/math in there? If yes, what size (e.g. _s=5_ and _t=3_)? Or just two rectangles with _s_ and _t_ written on the outside? What have you tried so far? Why do you think that didn't work? ... So please, improve your question with specifics.

Answer (score 5):

Should it be `(s+t)^2=2s^2`? In this case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw (0,0) -- (1.412,0) -- (1.412,-1.412) -- (0,-1.412) -- cycle;
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,-1) -- (0,-1) -- cycle;
\node at (.5,.2) {\Large $s$};
\node at (1.206,.2) {\Large $t$};
\node at (-.2,-.5) {\Large $s$};
\node at (-.2,-1.206) {\Large $t$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

**Edit:** Thanks to @TomBombadil for pointing out that the above `tikzpicture` can be improved this way:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw (0,0) rectangle ({sqrt(2)},{-sqrt(2)});
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,-1);
\node at (.5,.2) {\Large $s$};
\node at (1.206,.2) {\Large $t$};
\node at (-.2,-.5) {\Large $s$};
\node at (-.2,-1.206) {\Large $t$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much Matt.